# Do if column is empty instead of first cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

The code at the bottom checks to see if cell (1,b) is empty and then copies in a column and performs a text to columns on it. However I would like it to check if column b is empty instead of just this first cell. It should be straightforward but any changes I have made have not worked. For example I have tried:

```
If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Columns(b)) <> 1048576 Then
b = b+1
```

Instead of:

```
If Cells(1, b) <> "" Then b = b + 1
```

Please Help!

```
For a = 2 To 60

If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Excel.Sheets("Paste In").Columns(a)) <> 1048576 Then

    Excel.Sheets("Paste In").Columns(a).Copy

    b = Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).column

    Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Select


    If Cells(1, b) <> "" Then b = b + 1


        Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Columns(b).EntireColumn.Select
        Excel.ActiveSheet.Paste

        Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, b), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
                Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End If
```

Next a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the worksheet function to count nonempty cells in a column with column index a:

`If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Excel.Sheets("Paste In").Columns(a)) > 0 Then`

you have both a as b in your code, please use this code for both instances:

line 2 (`If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Excel.Sheets("Paste In").Columns(a)) <> 1048576 Then`) becomes:

`If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Excel.Sheets("Paste In").Columns(a)) > 0 Then`

line 6 (`If Cells(1, b) <> "" Then b = b + 1`) becomes:

`If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Columns(b)) > 0 Then`

Comment: also this works well even if the excel file has a different number of rows

Comment: thanks but that's giving me similar results. Won't I need to change the following line of code as well?    b = Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).column

Comment: if this doesnt solve your issue, then you might want to rephrase your issue, as in your original post you referred to this line to be your problem. Please explain what the problem is if not this.

Comment: Sorry you are right my question was phrased in a confusing way. I do want to check if column b is empty but as you'll see from the code, column b is supposed to be changing. b was not a good choice for the interation. The code should copy one column from the 'Paste In' sheet then go to the 'TOP LINE' sheet, check the first column (column b) to see if it is blank. If it isn't blank then increase b by 1 and check the next column (now column b). Paste to the first empty column. Sorry is that clearer?

Comment: yes clearer! now apply my code for a and for b in your code so also for the part `If Cells(1, b) <> "" Then b = b + 1`

Comment: I'm getting 'application defined or object defined error' when I try to apply it my code. Would you mind adjusting my code above, I think I'm not following you correctly? Thanks K_B

Comment: Did you just respond to my last comment before I commented. thats impressive :)

Comment: I've kept everything the same as my original code except for the 2 line changes that you specified but now the TOP LINE sheet is blank. Am I leaving something out? Does line 4 have to change?

Comment: Your code copies from sheet "Paste in" and pastes to sheet "TOP LINE" that is correct?

Comment: what you want accoplished with line 4 is up to you, if you change it from `b= xxxx` into `xxxx.select` you can visually verify if the correct column is selected for your purpose

Comment: yep thats correct. I am wondering is it a problem with the data coming in or something. I think the code may be still checking the first cell in column b as well as the whole column, is that possible do you think?

Comment: I think I've identified the problem. Its in line 9-14 (text to columns section). I think the rest of the original code and the code you have provided both work as required so I am going to accept your answer and start a new query. Thanks for all your help and time K_B